# Is it possible to remove a single file from PHP APC cache?

Tags: php, apc

I've got PHP APC running on my CentOS server, with **apc.stat = 0**  for performance reasons

There are certain PHP files that change fairly frequently that i'd like to be able to remove from the APC cache at will - is is possible to remove single files from the cache?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Would you believe

[apc_delete_file()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-delete-file.php)

or you can do it manually using apc.php

Comment: I don't seem to have the apc_*() functions compiled in, but i'll take a look. How do you know how to delete the file using apc.php? I can only see any option to clear the whole cache, even once logged in

Comment: Hmmm. yeah, I modified apc.php to add the delete individual file from cache, so you won't have that as standard... but if the apc functions aren't compiled in, then apc.php itself wouldn't work at all, because it uses those functions

Comment: Well, i'm getting **Call to undefined function apc_delete_file()** when trying to use the function, so I guess that one is part of a newer version of APC than I have. I'll try and update that first. Thanks for your help

Comment: @fistameeny - APC >= version 3.1.1 ( 12th December 2008 )